# How would I monitor the running i/o statistics of an application?

Tags: monitoring, io

In windows I find it incredibly useful to monitor total I/O read bytes to give myself an idea of how long a command line process is taking/will take to execute a task.  For example, for `capinfos`:

[image]

How would I get this information in linux?

Answer (score 4):

`iotop` let you monitor the I/O consumption of each running process :

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
sudo iotop -a
```

(`-a` option is to display accumulated I/O instead of bandwidth)

[image]

---

For example, if I want to monitor Firefox I will run :

```
sudo iotop -ap 3120
```

(Where `3120` is the PID of Firefox)

Comment: This is close to what I need, but it looks like it only displays bytes read from the time iotop has started, not total.

Comment: You can add `iotop` as a startup application ? =)